# Descargar CSV de registros de Base de Datos

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy intentando descargar un cvs de los registros de una tabla.

```
<form method="post">
    <button type="submit" id="export_csv_data" name='export_csv_data' value="Export to CSV" class="btn btn-info">Export to CSV</button>
</form> 
<?php 
if(isset($_POST["export_csv_data"])) {
    header("Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Solicitudes.csv");
    $output = fopen( 'php://output', 'w' );
    fputcsv($output, array('Documento', 'Nombre','Email','Direccion','Telefono'));
    $table = $db->query("SELECT * FROM  add_courier WHERE status_courier='Delivered' ORDER BY id DESC");
    while($row = $table->fetch_assoc()) {
        fputcsv($output, $row);
    }
        fclose($output);
    }
?>
```

pero al darle al boton en lugar de descargar un archivo me sale de la siguiente forma.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Es un problema con la escritura anticipada en la salida. Debes condicionar la visualizacion del formulario o cualquier salida antes de las llamadas a `header()` para que result. Lo ideal seria que coloques el codigo de descarga al inicio del script PHP. Ademas, terminar el script al enviar los datos (`exit`):

```
 <?php 
if(isset($_POST["export_csv_data"])) {
    header("Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Solicitudes.csv");
    $output = fopen( 'php://output', 'w' );
    fputcsv($output, array('Documento', 'Nombre','Email','Direccion','Telefono'));
    $table = $db->query("SELECT * FROM  add_courier WHERE status_courier='Delivered' ORDER BY id DESC");
    while($row = $table->fetch_assoc()) {
        fputcsv($output, $row);
    }
    fclose($output);
    exit;
}
?>
<form method="post">
    <button type="submit" id="export_csv_data" name='export_csv_data' value="Export to CSV" class="btn btn-info">Export to CSV</button>
</form>
```

https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.header.php

> Recuerde que header() debe ser llamado antes de mostrar nada por
> pantalla, etiquetas HTML, líneas en blanco desde un fichero o desde
> PHP. Es un error muy común leer código con funciones como include o
> require, u otro tipo de funciones de acceso de ficheros que incluyen
> espacios o líneas en blanco que se muestran antes de llamar a la
> función header(). Sucede el mismo problema cuando se utiliza un solo
> fichero PHP/HTML.

Comment: le puse el exit, y ahora solo se queda cargando :(

Comment: Si no colocas el exit, que pasa?

Comment: si no le pongo el exit sale tal cual como mostré en la imagen.